# Python running setup.py through cmd doesn't work?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to install via cmd using a setup.py file..
[image]

However, when I try to install it through CMD, this happens:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you were trying to install it is correct `python setup.py install`, however you need Python 2.x for this installer to work. You are in a Python 3.2 environment and it appears that this module has not been updated to work with Python3 at this time.

http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/manual/installation.html

The `print bdist.bdist_base, self.install_dir` statement is Python 2.x syntax. If it were compatible with Python3, it would be `print(bdist.bdist_base, self.install_dir)`

**----------**

If you require development in both Python3 and Python2, I highly recommend installing Anaconda

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

You can set up multiple environments with whatever versions of Python that you want. Then you can activate each one as necessary.

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

Comment: I tried it with python 2.7, and it still doesn't work.   https://i.gyazo.com/59b122ebba8fca7fe29bf5165a576152.png

Comment: What is the error message that you get with Python 2.7?

Comment: OK. That is because you are in the Python shell. You need to type `exit()` to get out of it. Then type `python setup.py -install` from your regular command shell.

Comment: That worked. I guess I just assumed being in the python shell meant the first python wasn't necessary. Mucho gracias